# Counterpoint: Do parallel 5ths and Octaves count even if they are not from the same voices

Tags: counterpoint

I tried to do another exercise today and I really liked what I had done but looking back I noticed what could be parallel 5ths. If you look at the following exercise, you can see the 4th and 5th chords both have 5ths but they are not resulting from the same voices. Is this a problem or is it allowed if the 5th comes from different voices?

[image]

Comment: Please mark or point the specific chords and notes in question.

Comment: You are making good progress but I think you should examine your use of the mediant chord - Bm. In a major key it is quite a weak chord and in my view you fall back on it too often which detracts from your coundterpoint. It's your choice of course but there are usually better solutions. Here is a short overview:  https://myweb.fsu.edu/nrogers/Handouts/iii.pdf

Comment: Thanks Ian. Up until now I have been taught to use intervals and to place them as I have done in the exercise to name the chords. This does not include the scale degrees upon which the chords are being built. If using a mediant chord too often is "weak" then why are only intervals marked and discussed in these exercises? From studying harmony i know what you mean about the mediant chord but because I am just numbering the intervals here, I didn't even realise I was using the mediant chord :)

Comment: You will have to make decisions like this all the time. Generally, if it is counterpoint I would let the counterpoint take precedence over harmony if you have to make a choice.